# Why defining class headers without CUDA __device__ attribute works? (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, class, header, cuda

I have a .h file with the following declarations:

```
class Foo{
public:
    inline int getInt();
};
```

and my .cu file defines the following:

```
__device__ int Foo::getInt(){
   return 42;
}
```

This is pretty awesome, because althought I cannot actually call `getInt` from host, I can include the .h file in .cpp files so I have the type declaration visible for the host. But for me it doesn't seem it should work, so why I dont need to put the `__device__` attribute on the .h file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works, it should not. It is probably a bug in a CUDA compiler and it might get fixed in the future - so do not rely on it.

However, if you want the class to be visible for the host (and non-cuda compiler), but you have some `__device__` functionality which you don't need on the host, you can always encapsulate those functions with the `#ifdef __CUDACC__` -- `#endif`. The `__CUDACC__` is predefined when compiling with nvcc, otherwise it is not. So you can write in your header something like:

```
class Foo{
public:
#ifdef __CUDACC__
    inline __device__ int getInt();
#endif
};
```

If you are afraid of having too many preprocessor ifdefs, you can also do a trick as follows:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define HOST __host__
#define DEVICE __device__
#else
#define HOST
#define DEVICE
#endif

...

class Foo{
public:
    inline HOST DEVICE int getInt();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this `__CUDACC__` will be very usefull for this and other things.

Comment: Is it possible to use this technique to define attributes also? Because I'm getting a `attribute "device" does not apply here` error when I try to define a `__device__  int test` inside Foo

Comment: No, you never write `__device__` for fields. Fields just specify the type and are not variables on their own. If you write `__device__ Foo var` then all fields of `var` will be on the device. Similarly goes for other memory spaces (shared, constant).

Comment: Oh of course, makes sense. If the object is instantiated on device memory, the fields will be on device memory, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
__device__ int Foo::getInt(){
   return 42;
}
```

The problem is the return type of the function. It isn't `void` it is `int`.

Comment: sorry, it is int, my mistake writing it here. This code works. I've changed the question to make it clear what I want to know.