# Regarding use of __device__ for variables

Tags: memory, cuda

I am using a global variable say d_myVar, which will be allocated device memory using cudaMalloc in main function. I am not clear, should I use __ device __ in front of it while doing global declaration? I ask this, since if it were local variable in host and was passed to a kernel, we would not write __ device __ in front of it. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012304/why-defining-class-headers-without-cuda-device-attribute-works-c?

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of that particular question.

Comment: I think, my question is little different. I have only one .cu file and I want to have global variables. I have no cpp file. I want to understand, when to define a global variable, which is allocated device memory as __ device __. Can we do without it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Globally-scoped `__device__` variables are not allocated with `cudaMalloc`.  Simply annotate a variable in the global scope with `__device__`:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 __device__ int d_myVar;

 __global__ void foo()
 {
   printf("d_myVar is %d\n", d_myVar);
 }

 int main()
 {
   int h_myVar = 13;
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_myVar, &h_myVar, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   foo<<<1,1>>>();
   cudaThreadSynchronize();
   return 0;
 }
```

The result:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu -run
d_myVar is 13
```

Comment: Great! Since it is not allocated, I need not free it also, right? Also, can I have arrays (size known at compile time) like this? But 3.2.2 of programming guide shows how to allocate arrays like that (1. cudaMalloc and 2. cudMemcpyToSymbol). Can you comment. Thanks for useful info.

Comment: @user1118148 That's correct, you need not free it.  Not sure if you can have ```__device__```-annotated arrays. Try it and see what happens.